# Why Is a:hover slower than td:hover?

Tags: html, css

I re-developed a page of ours, and I noticed it was using hovers against `<td>` elements, despite the click event being for the `<a>` tag.  So I changed it to hover against the `<a>` tag.  When mousing over each element quite fast it takes quite a while to catch up.  I don't suppose anyone knows why hovering an `<a>` tag in a large set of data would be slower than hovering the `<td>`?

Cheers

**EDIT** This is for changing the background colour.  The `td` element has the padding removed, the `a` tag has `padding:2px 4px` or something along those lines, then `a:hover { background-color:#ccc; }` is set.  This performs much slower than `td:hover { background-color:#ccc; }`

Comment: More css rules at the same time? a link has the :hover, :active, an :visited statuses, and the browser has to run them

Comment: Which browsers are you seeing this behaviour in?

Comment: Also, what action does the hover trigger - what does it do?

Comment: @JamesB: IE8 (not a fan, but it's a requirement).
@graphicdivine: It changes the background colour.

Comment: Is the 'a' tag definitely closed?

Comment: Kezzer: Hmm. Well then, the only thing to do is to reproduce it in a standalone page, and see if you get the same effect. I do think, though, that it's probably due to some unclosed tag.

Answer (score 2):

Explained pretty well here: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html